# An error occurred while loading the map layer 'default': Shape Plugin: shapefile 'true.shp' does not exist

Tags: postgresql, render, openstreetmap, mapnik, osm2pgsql

I'm trying to setup a tileserver that serves tiles from somewhere. 
I've followed [this](https://wiki.debian.org/OSM/tileserver/jessie) tutorial :

It almost works, but at the end, when I run the following command : `su username -c "renderd -f -c /usr/local/etc/renderd.conf"`, I have this error :

> renderd[10379]: An error occurred while loading the map layer 'default': Shape Plugin: shapefile 'true.shp' does not exist  encountered during parsing of layer 'coast-poly' in Layer of '/home/osm/openstreetmap-carto-2.29.1/style.xml'

My useful parts of /usr/local/etc/renderd.conf are :

```
[mapnik]
plugins_dir=/usr/local/lib/mapnik/input/
font_dir=/usr/share/fonts/truetype
font_dir_recurse=1

[default]
URI=/osm_tiles/
TILEDIR=/var/lib/mod_tile
XML=/home/osm/openstreetmap-carto-2.29.1/style.xml
HOST=localhost
TILESIZE=256
```

Can anyone help me on this ? Any ideas ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution.

The problem came from Mapnik version.

If someone needs to install such a server, you can follow [this](https://ircama.github.io/osm-carto-tutorials/tile-server-ubuntu/#install-mapnik-library-from-package) updated tutorial, for Ubuntu 18.04 and 16.04.